# Jupiter Lab on cluster with shared storage

Tags: jupyter-lab

I'm on a slurm cluster with a bunch of nodes. I want to run two seperate notebooks, on two seperate nodes. Unfortunatley, when I run two jupyter lab instances, they wind up clobbering .ipynb_checkpoint and other hidden files that are essential for jupyter, even if they use differrent ports. I think this is because they are sharing the same home directory. I'm wondering if there is some addon which will allow me to select which node to use when initializing a kernel, but I can't find it.

Comment: I know the question is 1 year old. Are you looking to port forward two jupyter lab servers from different login nodes. that is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soloution was to start jupyter lab instances on different nodes from different directories (starting them in the same directory causes them to clobber each other). I don't know why this didn't work before. Watch out for editing the same file in two different instances though.